# Dailymotion embedded player set parameters

Tags: video, dailymotion-api

I read https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-parameters and this is my embed code

```
<iframe src='http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/VIDEO_ID?quality=240&info=0&logo=0' allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

but none of these parameters work. quality always set to auto, info and logo always appear. what I'm missing?

thanks

Comment: These parameters work perfectly, just tested now. What device are you using?

Comment: thanks it work now, the problem was my html cache that still use old url.

Comment: alright, I'll just add my comment as answer so the question is solved

Answer (score 1):

there is no issue with the player parameters, they all work like a charm.

The comments below the question says that the issue was due to html cache, so clearing the cache solved the issue.